# Quickblox android API for chat messaging free or not?

Tags: android, quickblox

I have used git hub code sample .It work very good i want to develop a application using this api but i am confused this api free or not.If not than what type of payment plan they have.
I have already to visit Quickblox website's plan section but i don't understand about their plan

Comment: this is paid service....not free registration or testing purpouse this is free only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QuickBlox offers a starter tier which you can use absolutely free. All you need is register a free QuickBlox account and add your App there.

Each tier has particular server configuration. E.g. with free tier you can have 20/s chat messages, 1000 concurrent users, 20/s notifications etc (check [details](http://quickblox.com/plans/)).

If you feel that free tier is not enough for you, you can upgrade to bigger plan any time. Besides if you are looking for good quality and support you should pay attention to Pro and Enterprise plans.